# LinkedIn Integration in iOS: Invitation API not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to integrate **LinkedIn** in my iOS application, where I need to Authenticate, then fetch profile details and post to LinkedIn from my app. I do all these things quite successfully using this sample project [LinkedIn OAuth Sample Client](https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client) as reference, I did some modifications and everything is working quite well. And I use the details from 
[LinnkedIn API](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) as well to implement this. 
Next, **I need to send invitation to connect in LinkedIn** from the same app. I tried using [Invitataion API](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/invitation-api) .

Here is my code snippet:

```
-(void)sendInvitationToconnectTo:(NSString *)emailAddress withMessage:(NSString *)text

{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"];    
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                    consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                       token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                    callback:nil
                           signatureProvider:[[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init]];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSDictionary *temp=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"/people/email=userName@gmail.com",@"_path",@"userName1",@"first-name",@"userName2",@"last-name", nil];

    NSDictionary *temp2=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:temp,@"person",nil];
    NSArray *arr2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:temp2, nil];
    NSDictionary *value=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arr2,@"values", nil];
    NSDictionary *dict3=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"friend",@"connect-type",nil];
    NSDictionary *dict4=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:dict3,@"invitation-request", nil];

    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:dict4,@"item-content",@"Say yes!",@"body",@"Invitation to connect.",@"subject",value,@"recipients", nil];

    NSString *updateString = [dict JSONString];
    NSLog(@"updateString : %@",updateString);

    [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(sendRequestApiCallResult:didFinish:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(sendRequestApiCallResult:didFail:)];
    [request release];
}



- (void)sendRequestApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data

{
    NSLog(@"invitation sent");
    [self networkApiCall];
}

- (void)sendRequestApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFail:(NSData *)error

{
    NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

And my json string looks like this:

> {"body":"Say yes!","subject":"Invitation to
>   connect.","recipients":{"values":[{"person":{"first-name":"userName1","last-name":"userName2","_path":"/people/email=userName@gmail.com"}}]},"item-content":{"invitation-request":{"connect-type":"friend"}}}

While sending the invitation **I don't get any errors** and when I debug, the `sendRequestApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data` method gets called showing *invitation sent* text.
But ths issue is **the target LinkedIn user didn't get any request!**

Can anyone help me regarding this? Is there anything I'm doing wrong in my code?

**NB** I went through both the below mentioned links to get a solution, tried the solutions , but in vain.

1.[Invitation API - Stumped by 401 (iOS and OAuthConsumer) - SOLVED](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/invitation-api-stumped-401-ios-and-oauthconsumer-solved)
2.[linkedin connect API gives error 401 - iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452212/linkedin-connect-api-gives-error-401-iphone)

and the `NSURLResponse` statuscode I get is 401 !

**EDIT:: Solved it myself. See my answer below.**

Comment: hey.. please answer this question if you can... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909797/how-to-invite-friends-using-linkedin-sdk-in-ios-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glad to inform all that after long 4 days of continuos research, I got this problem solved! 
I got the solution from this [Linkedin thread](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2856?page=1#comment-23330)

You just need to make a few changes in the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"];

    OAMutableURLRequest *request =
    [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
    consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
    token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
    callback:nil
    signatureProvider:nil];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *messageToPerson = @"/people/email=target@gmail.com";
    NSDictionary *person = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:messageToPerson,@"_path",@"TargetFirstName",@"first-name",@"TargetSecondName",@"last-name",nil] autorelease], @"person",nil]; 
    NSArray *valueArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:person,nil];
    NSDictionary *values = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:valueArray,@"values", nil];
    NSDictionary *ir = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"friend",@"connect-type",nil] autorelease], @"invitation-request",nil];
    NSDictionary *ic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:ir,@"item-content", nil];
    NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:values,@"recipients",@"Invitation",@"subject",@"ConnectWithMe",@"body", ir, @"item-content", nil];
    [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[update description]);
    NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

    [request prepare];

    [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request delegate:self         didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)         didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:) withId:1];

    [request release];
```

and 
in `oAdata OADataFetcher.m`

```
- (void)fetchDataWithRequest:(OAMutableURLRequest *)aRequest delegate:(id)aDelegate didFinishSelector:(SEL)finishSelector didFailSelector:(SEL)failSelector  withId:(int)idtm     {
     [request release];     
request = [aRequest retain];
     delegate = aDelegate;     
didFinishSelector = finishSelector;
     didFailSelector = failSelector;

//note this change
     if (idtm!=1) {
        [request prepare];     
       }

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:aRequest delegate:self];     
}
```

Try this. Will work for sure. Hope this will help future visitors.

Regards

Comment: @MicRo: what should I done in didFinishSelector and didFailSelector. Then in connection delegate what should i want to done to send connection request

Comment: hey.. please answer this question if you can... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909797/how-to-invite-friends-using-linkedin-sdk-in-ios-app