# send Message between Connections in Linkedin (iOS ) ?

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I am using demo project(iPhone OAuth Starter Kit) with modification . I wanna send message to my whist list connections .   I also tried ([LinkedIn Integration in iOS: Invitation API not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848463/linkedin-integration-in-ios-invitation-api-not-working) ) this approach and still not able to send  message and also read linked Developer.com . Can someone refer me any link from where i could solve this problem.